# Set ipython notebook working directory to notebook location

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering if there is a way to set the working directory of an ipython/jupyter notebook to the current location of the ipynb file. Something along the lines of

```
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

in mathematica or

```
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

in python. The issue is that the __file__ variable is not defined in an ipython notebook, or at least doesn't seem to be.